# How fast does NSOpenGLView redraw? Does it have a default FPS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, 3d, frame-rate

I am creating a Cocoa application in Xcode 6, and the application uses an OpenGLView. The draw method in my extension of NSOpenGLView is getting called repeatedly, but I am not sure at which rate it is being called or a way to set the rate.

Is there a default "framerate" for NSOpenGLView, and is there a way to change it?

Comment: Regardless of a target FPS, the frequency of a draw request should generally not be used for timing ..

Comment: @user2864740 that is a good point. Since the OpenGL context is already established, is it safe to just draw from another class / timing system? I'm new to Objective C (most of my experience is in C++ on Windows) so I'm still getting used to the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in any window system, the window is not redrawn on a periodic schedule; it only happens in response to events that cause a *"damaged"* or *"dirty"* state.

The number of things that cause this *"damaged"* state has gotten a lot smaller in recent years thanks to compositing window managers (OS X uses one such window manager). It used to happen whenever a window moved over top it, but in modern window managers it only happens during/after a resize event or when the window is moved.

#### As you would expect, Cocoa's documentation says the same thing:

> ```
> - update
> ```
>
> > Called by Cocoa when the view’s window moves or when the view itself moves or is resized.

---

#### Owen Taylor writes an [excellent blog](http://blog.fishsoup.net/page/2/); this diagram illustrates what may happen:

[image: http://owtaylor.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/benchmark-method-late-damage.png?w=640&h=239]

> If a compositor isn’t redrawing immediately when it receives damage from a client, but is waiting a bit for more damage, then it’s possible it might wait too long and miss the vertical reblank entirely. Then the frame rate could drop way down, even if there was plenty of CPU and GPU available.

Comment: Ok, good to know! In this case, I should do the rendering in its own timing loop.

Comment: @LukasPalmer: Basically, yes. The only time you would really pay attention to `update` is if you were developing an application with a static UI. This callback would give you the minimum set of situations where you were required to redraw. For interactive rendering you're generally going to draw everything repeatedly regardless whether the window is resized or obstructed (which is what causes "damage").

Comment: Would setting an NSTimer that repeatedly calls my draw function be the best way to go?

Comment: @LukasPalmer: I know nothing about your software requirements so I could not say. Generally, no I would not go that route. I like to draw in one continuous loop and measure the interval between each frame for any timing. With VSYNC on, the driver will throttle this loop for you (some GL command will block the calling thread) if you get too far ahead of the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

[Apple has a technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1385/_index.html) describing how to drive an OpenGL rendering loop. The answer is to use a CoreVideo display link (`CVDisplayLink`), it will call a callback during the blanking interval.